# current_user is blank after being assigned in application_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I'm working with the parse_resource gem (https://github.com/adelevie/parse_resource) for authentication. I'm trying to create a forum using the gem forum_monster (https://github.com/gitt/forum_monster). The issue is that it requires that the user model be an ActiveRecord, but to use parse_resource, the user model needs to be ParseUser. So right now things aren't working.

My plan of attack is that I'm attempting to abstract the parse authentication to a Parseuser model, along with a User model that is ActiveRecord so forum_monster won't complain. My problem is that the current_user is blank for some reason.

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

My Parseuser model:

```
class Parseuser < ParseUser
end
```

My ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    helper_method :current_user  

    private  
    def current_user  
        @current_user ||= Parseuser.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end 

end
```

Parseuser.find should work in the application controller because Parseuser.authenticate works perfectly in the sessions controller.

I've checked session[:user_id] and it has been populated correctly, so that is not the issue either.